# Joining two graphics to make a diagram

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to join two graphics (`defel` and `masterel`) into one figure, but they are superposing each other. How can i do that? 
Here is the code that generates the two graphics:

```
 topol = {{1, 2, 3, 4}}
eltype = 2;
forcing = 0.;
nnodes = {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
meshVis1 = 
  Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1.5}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1.5, 0}}], 
    FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
    GraphicsComplex[nnodes, Polygon[topol[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]]]}];
dists1 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, -1.1}, {1/Sqrt[3], -1.1}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, -1.1}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), -1.1}}], 
    Arrow[{{1/Sqrt[3], -1.1}, {0, -1.1}}], 
    Arrow[{{-(1/Sqrt[3]), -1.1}, {0, -1.1}}], FaceForm[], 
    EdgeForm[Black]}];
dists2 = Graphics[{Arrow[{{-1.1, 0}, {-1.1, 1/Sqrt[3]}}], 
    Arrow[{{-1.1, 0}, {-1.1, -(1/Sqrt[3])}}], 
    Arrow[{{-1.1, 1/Sqrt[3]}, {-1.1, 0}}], 
    Arrow[{{-1.1, -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {-1.1, 0}}]}, FaceForm[], 
   EdgeForm[Black]];
nodeVis = Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Medium], Point[nnodes]}];
pts = {{-(1/Sqrt[3]), -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {1/
    Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[3]}};
ptstext = 
  Graphics[{Style[Text["0.57735", {-0.57735/2, -1.2}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["0.57735", {0.57735/2, -1.2}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["0.57735", {-1.2, 0.57735/2}, Automatic, {0, 1}], 
     Medium], 
    Style[Text["0.57735", {-1.2, -0.57735/2}, Automatic, {0, 1}], 
     Medium]}];
integartionpoints = Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}];
axes = Graphics[{Style[Text["\[Xi]", {1.4, -0.2}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["\[Eta]", {0.2, 1.4}], Medium]}];
coords = Graphics[{Style[Text["(-1,-1)", {-1.1, -1.1}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["(1,-1)", {1.1, -1.1}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["(1,1)", {1.1, 1.1}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["(-1,1)", {-1.1, 1.1}], Medium]}];
masterel = 
 Show[meshVis1, nodeVis, axes, coords, integartionpoints, dists1, 
  dists2, ptstext]
(*Export["C:\\Users\\diogo\\Dropbox\\ArtigoFemMathematica\\figuras\\\
masterel.jpg",masterel,ImageResolution\[Rule]300]*)

topol = {{1, 2, 3, 4}}
eltype = 2;
forcing = 0.;
nnodes = {{2, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 6}, {1, 4}};
meshVis2 = 
  Graphics[{Arrow[{{0.6, 0.5}, {6, 0.5}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.6, 0.5}, {0.6, 6}}], FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
    GraphicsComplex[nnodes, Polygon[topol[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]]]}];
nodeVis2 = Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Medium], Point[nnodes]}];
axes2 = Graphics[{Style[Text["x", {5.8, 0.25}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["y", {0.4, 5.8}], Medium]}];
coords2 = 
  Graphics[{Style[Text["(2,1)", {1.8, 0.8}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["(5,2)", {5.3, 1.8}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["(4,6)", {4.3, 6.2}], Medium], 
    Style[Text["(1,4)", {0.9, 4.2}], Medium]}];
defel = Show[meshVis2, nodeVis2, axes2, coords2]
Show[masterel, defel]
```

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you sketch how the output is supposed to look like?

Comment: @Felix i have edited the question including a skech.

Comment: Instead of `Show`, use `GraphicsRow[{defel, masterel}, ImageSize -> Large]`; it generates [this figure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VscoC.png).

Comment: Is this question solved by @MarcoB 's comment?

Comment: @MarcoB thank you. Do you know how to draw te curved arrow linking the two figures?

Comment: @Felix, yes  his comment solved my problem.

Comment: @Diogo You can add an appropriate `Graphics@Arrow[...]` into the `GraphicsRow[{defel, arrow, masterel}, ...]`.

Comment: Then this solution should be posted as an answer an be accepted to indicate that it's solved, shouldn't it?

Comment: I guess you could feed the two `Graphics[]` objects to an `Inset[]` as well...

Comment: For future reference, please post a *minimal* working sample. You could have generated 2 small simple graphics instead, making your code two lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are not joining two `Graphics` expressions; you are trying to join too many `Graphics` expressions. The solution is to work with one `Graphics` expression, which is actually quite easy to do.

I will build up the two main components of your final image from more elementary elements just as you did. I will also build each of the main components in its own coordinate space as you did. I will make the final image by translating and scaling the first the main component.

First component

```
topol = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
eltype = 2;
nnodes1 = {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
pts = 
  {{-(1/Sqrt[3]), -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[3])}, 
   {1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), 1/Sqrt[3]}};

meshVis1 =
  {Arrowheads[.01],
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1.5}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1.5, 0}}],
   FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black],
   GraphicsComplex[nnodes1, Polygon[topol[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]]]};

dists1 =
  {Arrowheads[.01],
   Arrow[{{0, -1.1}, {1/Sqrt[3], -1.1}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, -1.1}, {-(1/Sqrt[3]), -1.1}}], 
   Arrow[{{1/Sqrt[3], -1.1}, {0, -1.1}}], 
   Arrow[{{-(1/Sqrt[3]), -1.1}, {0, -1.1}}]};

dists2 =
  {Arrowheads[.01],
   Arrow[{{-1.1, 0}, {-1.1, 1/Sqrt[3]}}], 
   Arrow[{{-1.1, 0}, {-1.1, -(1/Sqrt[3])}}], 
   Arrow[{{-1.1, 1/Sqrt[3]}, {-1.1, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{-1.1, -(1/Sqrt[3])}, {-1.1, 0}}]};

nodeVis = {PointSize[Medium], Point[nnodes1]};

ptstext =
  {Text["0.57735", {-0.57735/2, -1.2}],
   Text["0.57735", {0.57735/2, -1.2}],
   Text["0.57735", {-1.2, 0.57735/2}, Automatic, {0, 1}],
   Text["0.57735", {-1.2, -0.57735/2}, Automatic, {0, 1}]};

integartionpoints = {PointSize[Large], Point[pts]};

axeslbls = {Text["ξ", {1.4, -0.2}], Text["η", {0.2, 1.4}]};

coordlbls =
  {Text["(-1, -1)", {-1.1, -1.1}], Text["(1, -1)", {1.1, -1.1}],
   Text["(1, 1)", {1.1, 1.1}], Text["(-1, 1)", {-1.1, 1.1}]};
```

Second component

```
topol = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
eltype = 2;
nnodes2 = {{2, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 6}, {1, 4}};

meshVis2 =
  {Arrow[{{0.6, 0.5}, {6, 0.5}}],
   Arrow[{{0.6, 0.5}, {0.6, 6}}], FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
   GraphicsComplex[nnodes2, Polygon[topol[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]]]]};

nodeVis2 = {PointSize[Medium], Point[nnodes]};

axeslbls2 = {Text["x", {5.8, 0.25}], Text["y", {0.4, 5.8}]};

coordlbls2 =
  {Text["(2, 1)", {1.8, 0.8}], Text["(5, 2)", {5.3, 1.8}], 
   Text["(4, 6)", {4.3, 6.2}], Text["(1, 4)", {0.9, 4.2}]};
```

Now all I have to do is translate and scale the first component and add a curved arrow.

```
Graphics[
  {Scale[
     Translate[
       {meshVis1, nodeVis, axeslbls, coordlbls, integartionpoints, 
        dists1, dists2, ptstext}, 
       {11, 4}], 
     2],
   {Arrowheads[.025], Arrow[BezierCurve[{{5.5, 5}, {6.5, 5.3}, {7.5, 5}}]]},
   {meshVis2, nodeVis2, axeslbls2, coordlbls2}},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: diagram]